# MongoDB - Find the latest trading data for every stock

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

My collection is a time-series collection with the following format

```
{
    ticker : "AAPL",
    date : ISODate("2016-10-18 08:00.000"),
    close : 120,
},
{
    ticker : "MSFT",
    date : ISODate("2016-10-18 08:00.000"),
    close : 50,
},
{
    ticker : "AAPL",
    date : ISODate("2016-12-18 08:00.000"),
    close : 160,
},
{
    ticker : "MSFT",
    date : ISODate("2017-10-18 08:00.000"),
    close : 40,
}
```

I want this to return the latest data for all tickers. How would one do that, using either basic filters or aggregate request.

This is what the output response needs to be:

```
[{
    ticker : "AAPL",
    date : ISODate("2016-12-18 08:00.000"),
    close : 160,
},
{
    ticker : "MSFT",
    date : ISODate("2017-10-18 08:00.000"),
    close : 40,
}]
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

1. `$sort` - Sort by `ticker` ASC and `date` DESC.
2. `$group` - Group by `ticker` and take the first document into `data`.
3. `$replaceWith` - Replace the input documents with `data`.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $sort: {
      ticker: 1,
      date: -1
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$ticker",
      data: {
        $first: "$$ROOT"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $replaceWith: "$data"
  }
])
```

[Sample Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/LkDnhR0jRJW)

Comment: You don't need the `$sort` stage in the pipeline. The `$max` aggregation operator can get the latest date for each group.